# Retrieve object value considering a key value range

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to retrieve an object value base on a key range condition?

For instance my Obj is

```
const ind_ind = {
            '25000':  200,
            '100000': 375,
            '200000': 750,
            '400000': 900
        }
```

The idea is to get the corresponding values considering those ranges

```
0 up to 25000;
25.001 up to 100.000; 
100.001 up to 200.000; 
above 200.001
```

So the expected output for these e.g. entries are

```
input is 5.000  outputs 200
input is 24.999 outputs 200
input is 25.000 outputs 200 
input is 25.001 outputs 375
input is 99.999 outputs 375
input is 100.000 outputs 375
input is 100.001 outputs 750
input is 199.999 outputs 750
input is 200.000 outputs 750
input is 200.001 outputs 900
input is 399.999 outputs 900
input is 400.000 outputs 900
input is 400.001 or above outputs 900
```

I hope to have clarify it enough to get my answer.

Appreciate any help

Comment: what have you tried sofar?

Comment: That, and how many keys could your object potentially have?

Comment: For this case all the keys are those already given

Comment: please update your question with expected results for 24999, 25000, 25001, 99999, 100000, 100001, 199999, 200000, 200001, 399999, 400000 and 400001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const ind_ind = {
  25000: 200,
  100000: 375,
  200000: 750,
  400000: 900,
};

const customFind = (val, obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).find(([k]) => val <= Number(k))?.[1] ??
  Object.values(obj).slice(-1)[0];

console.log(customFind(5000, ind_ind), "expected:", 200);
console.log(customFind(24999, ind_ind), "expected:", 200);
console.log(customFind(25000, ind_ind), "expected:", 200);
console.log(customFind(25001, ind_ind), "expected:", 375);
console.log(customFind(99999, ind_ind), "expected:", 375);
console.log(customFind(100000, ind_ind), "expected:", 375);
console.log(customFind(100001, ind_ind), "expected:", 750);
console.log(customFind(199999, ind_ind), "expected:", 750);
console.log(customFind(200000, ind_ind), "expected:", 750);
console.log(customFind(200001, ind_ind), "expected:", 900);
console.log(customFind(399999, ind_ind), "expected:", 900);
console.log(customFind(400000, ind_ind), "expected:", 900);
console.log(customFind(400001, ind_ind), "expected:", 900);
```

Comment: Should it be `val > Number(k)` or `val >= Number(k)` - I lean towards the latter :p

Comment: Agree, thanks! Good catch @JaromandaX

Comment: easy to catch since the code I *almost* posted just as your answer popped up was 99% the same :p - I like how you made it a one liner - mine was two lines :p

Comment: @MauricioRobayo Nevermind my last statement, thanks for answering

Comment: @augustus182l not sure about that, haven't tested there. The nullish-coalescing operator is well supported at the moment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#browser_compatibility

Comment: @MauricioRobayo The same as the first answer... 25100 should return 375 in this case, sorry had not seen it before

Comment: That's confusing @augustus182l... just guessing here,  but maybe this is what you want `const customFind = (val, obj) => Object.entries(obj).find(([k]) => val <= Number(k))?.[1]`, otherwise, would you mind clarifying the ranges and the expected output.

Comment: @MauricioRobayo done, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @augustus182l fixed according to your test cases.

Comment: Incredible how efficient and short your snippet is!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with the condition you want for the object keys.

Try like below:

```js
const ind_ind = {
  25000: 200,
  100000: 375,
  200000: 750,
  400000: 900,
};

const findValueForKeyLimit = (keyLimit) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(ind_ind).map((value) => parseInt(value));

  // Edge case when key limit is less than the first key
  if (keyLimit <= keys[0]) {
    return ind_ind[keys[0]];
  }

  const key = keys.find(
    (key, keyIndex) =>
      key <= keyLimit &&
      (keyIndex === keys.length - 1 || keyLimit < keys[keyIndex + 1])
  );

  if (key) {
    return ind_ind[key];
  }
  return null;
};

[24000, 25100, 101000, 200000, 403000].forEach((testValue) => {
  console.log(
    "input: ",
    testValue,
    "=> output: ",
    findValueForKeyLimit(testValue)
  );
});
```

Comment: Wow, this was fast! The only thing is that values under 25.000 should retrieve 200, as it's like up to 25.000

Comment: @augustus182l, Updated the answer with the edge condition

Comment: @augustus182l is this an edge case? or you are trying to get "the closest" your range condition is not clear. In all your examples you get back the option below. If your value was  99999 what should the method return? 200 because its below 100000 or 375 because its closer to 100000 than 25000.

Comment: @DanielCruz the idea is to get the corresponding values considering those ranges 0...25000 ; 25001...100000 ; 100001...200000 ; 200001...400000  and => 400001

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera maybe something is wrong with your snippet, because 25100 should return 375 in this case, sorry had not seen it before

Comment: @augustus182l - this last two comments seem to contradict your question ... can you update your question with expected results for 24999, 25000, 25001, 99999, 100000, 100001, 199999, 200000, 200001, 399999, 400000 and 400001 - that way all the possible ranges will be defined in the question

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to retrieve an object value base on a key range condition?

To search ranges, either use a linear_search for a smallish number of keys or use bisection for a larger number of keys.